# How to get all the results within radius from provided lat and long from MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

I have a MySQL table on my local server. The table includes latitude and longitude for places tagged by the users. I am trying to get all the id's who's tag their places within 1 kilometres from provided latitude and longitude. But my result is not expected.

Table: map_locations

```
id  user_id lat     lng     place_name
1   1   28.584688   77.31593    Sec 2, Noida
2   2   28.596026   77.314494   Sec 7, Noida
3   5   28.579876   77.356131   Sec 35, Noida
4   1   28.516831   77.487405   Surajpur, Greater Noida
5   1   28.631451   77.216667   Connaught Place, New Delhi
6   2   19.098003   72.83407    Juhu Airport, Mumbai
```

and here is PHP Script

```
$lat = '28.596026';
$long = '77.314494';
$query = "SELECT  id,
                  (6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians('lat') ) *
                        cos( radians('lng') - radians($long)) +
                        sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians('lat')) )
                  ) as distance
    FROM  map_locations
    HAVING  'distance' < 1
    ORDER BY  id
    LIMIT  25";

$_res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Error query:  '.$query);
$detail = array();
$i=0;
while($row = $_res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $detail[$i] = $row['id'];
    $i++;
}
print_r($detail);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
   [3] => 4
   [4] => 5
   [5] => 6
)
```

Query returns all the records from the table. Can anyone please let me know what's wrong in the query?

Comment: Can it be possible , that all records would be at same location or within 1 km, because your query seems perfect

Comment: Consider doing a row count so you know if there are any results.

Comment: @JayminNoob No its not possible, all records are not from within 1 km.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query contains some quoted strings like 'lat', 'long', and 'distance', where it should contain column names like lat, long, and distance.

In particular it ends with

```
 HAVING 'distance' < 0.5
```

That's always true, because MySQL always coerces strings to numbers when using them in a number context. It looks to MySQL like `HAVING 0 < 0.5`.  You want

```
 HAVING distance < 0.5
```

Try this query. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f5116/5/2)

```
SELECT id, 
       (6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians(lat) ) * 
        cos( radians(lng) - radians($long)) + sin(radians($lat)) *
        sin(radians(lat)) )) as distance 
  FROM map_locations
HAVING distance < 0.5
```

And, beware! When you get thousands of rows in your `map_locations` table this query will be slower than a New York bus in a traffic jam.  You should investigate using bounding boxes to speed it up. [Read this](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I was using Quotes for database columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be possible that all the records would be under 1 km, only thing I suggest you to try changing the distance.

Let me revise the query for you again and then check whether it is giving you a perfect result or not

```
$query = "SELECT id,(6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians('lat') ) * cos( radians('lng') - radians($long)) + sin(radians($lat)) * sin(radians('lat')) )) as distance FROM map_locations HAVING 'distance' < 0.5 ORDER BY id LIMIT 25";
```

Also you can check it further by changing the manually lat lng given,

```
$lat = '21.591026';
$long = '79.314994';
```

Let me know if any query occurs.

Comment: No modified query is also returning same result. I changed the lat and long but same result.